# Yesod - Couldn't match type `WidgetT site0 m0' with `HandlerT App IO'

Tags: haskell, yesod

I Scaffolded my site in Stack and actually i'm trying to add more pages (another issue for another day), so today i opened the code and:

```
[13 of 14] Compiling Handler.Vendita  ( src/Handler/Vendita.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-freebsd/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Handler/Vendita.o )

/usr/home/giulio/Lavori/karmen/src/Handler/Vendita.hs:20:4: error:
    * Couldn't match type `WidgetT site0 m0' with `HandlerT App IO'
      Expected type: HandlerT App IO Html
        Actual type: WidgetT site0 m0 ()
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        (asWidgetT GHC.Base.. toWidget)
          ((blaze-markup-0.8.2.0:Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText
              GHC.Base.. Data.Text.pack)
             "<main><h1>Canonical</h1>
</main>
")
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        (do (asWidgetT GHC.Base.. toWidget)
              ((blaze-markup-0.8.2.0:Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText
                  GHC.Base.. Data.Text.pack)
                 "<main><h1>Canonical</h1>
</main>
"))
      In the expression:
        do setTitle "Vendita"
           (do (asWidgetT GHC.Base.. toWidget)
                 ((blaze-markup-0.8.2.0:Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText
                     GHC.Base.. Data.Text.pack)
                    "<main><h1>Canonical</h1>
 </main>
 "))
   |
20 |  $(widgetFile "vendita")
   |    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

--  While building custom Setup.hs for package karmen-0.0.0 using:
      /usr/home/giulio/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-freebsd/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.0.1.0_ghc-8.2.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-freebsd/Cabal-2.0.1.0 build lib:karmen --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
```

The code work properly removing all the page, and changing the widget file from this to the homepage widget not resolve the problem.
Also copying the getHomeR code cause an error.
I also tried to add and remove isAuthenticated part to cause differents bugs.

Comment: It seems you forgot to add your code to the question, so you'll want to [edit] in the relevant parts of Venditta.hs. Going by just what I can see from the error message, you might be missing a `defaultLayout` call in line 20. Cf. [this passage of the Yesod book](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/scaffolding-and-the-site-template#scaffolding-and-the-site-template_widgetfile). (Note that I don't know much about Yesod myself, so I might be missing something too!)

Comment: Yeah, I resolved the problem so actually it's works